# Uses of Wien's law of displacement

Tags: temperature, astrophysics, thermal-radiation

Wiens's displacement law says $$λ_{\text{max}}T=\text{a constant}$$
So if I have the $λ_{\text{max}}$, I can find the temperature of a star. But if I have the temperature, is there any point in calculating $λ_{\text{max}}$? What information does that give us of the star, besides temperature?

Answer (score 0):

So, let's start with the formal definition of peak wavelength. Peak wavelength $(\lambda_{max})$ is the wavelength where an object absorbs the most photons (or, to our eyes, becomes more dark, or, at a darker point, completely isn't in the visible spectrum. (for a refresher, take a look at the electromagnetic spectrum, and here's something to look at as you go: [electromagnetic spectrum](https://www.clinuvel.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Electromagnetic-Spectrum-FINAL.jpg))

Well, back to your question, why do we even have $\lambda_{max}$, and what is it used for? So, I did a bit of research in an astrochemistry textbook that I have, and found a reason why peak wavelength is useful. It is useful as a parameter to compare the quality of several types of molecules.

Hopefully this was helpful in answering your question!